# SwiftUI keyboardShortcut with modifiers

Tags: swiftui

The SwiftUI documentation to `keyboardShortcut(_:modifiers:)` says:

> If multiple controls are associated with the same shortcut, the first one found is used.

So far so good. But this example is not working:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var shortcut = "none pressed"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text(self.shortcut)
            
            Button("shift left") {
                self.shortcut = "shift left pressed"
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(.leftArrow, modifiers: .shift)
            
            Button("left") {
                self.shortcut = "left pressed"
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(.leftArrow, modifiers: [])
            
            Button("right") {
                self.shortcut = "right pressed"
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(.rightArrow, modifiers: [])
            
            Button("shift right") {
                self.shortcut = "shift right pressed"
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(.rightArrow, modifiers: .shift)
            
            
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Here the shortcut "shift left" and "right" are working, no matter if I press the arrow keys with or without the shift modifier.

Is this intended? With using the modifiers it's not the same shortcut, but unfortunately I cannot use a shortcut with and without modifier besides each other. Is this a bug in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `.shift` modifier. If you use `.command` or `.option` it works like you’d expect. `.control` might work, too, but those keys are already mapped on macOS. I can’t say for sure, but I suspect `Shift+UpArrow` maps to `NumPad-8` on a standard keyboard.

Comment: No, it's not. Try removing the shortcuts for left and right (those without the modifier). Shift+arrow works perfectly.

Comment: but you're right: If I use .command, all the four buttons are working. That's strange

Comment: It sounds like the Arrow keys send the same code whether Shift is down or not, then. (On a Mac anyway.)